# How do notification, after download file?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, epplus

The essence of the problem is this: there is a controller, in which is a method that generates an excel file. Upon request by its need to generate and return. The file is generated for a long time for 1-2 hours, while it is necessary to highlight the text notifications, please wait. After finish notification must be removed.

I could not find my desired solutions.

I sory for my bad English

```
  public ActionResult DownloadFile()
    {
         return new FileStreamResult(_exporter.Export(), "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
    }
```

Comment: Notification needs to be done on a web page, it is itself already implemented, but I know how to call after the beginning of the process, but do not know how to turn off.

Comment: So is `_exporter.Export()` taking a long time?

Comment: 1-2 hours!  Not a great user experience. Is there another way to do this? Could you create the file on a server and notify the user by email or SMS?

Comment: @markpsmith It's an option, but still not as much as required. Necessary that the tab would be opened for two hours and there was a notification that the wait operation is performed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only get one bite at the response apple. If you return a file result, *that is all you can return*. The only way to handle this while giving the user updates about the status is to do the file creation out-of-stream and then long-poll or use Web Sockets to update the user periodically. The request to this action would merely queue up the file creation and then return a regular view result.

It's unwise to have particularly long running actions take place within the request-response cycle, anyways. A web server has a thread pool which is often referred to as its "max requests", because each request needs a thread. Usually this is set by default to something around a 1000, and assumes that you're going to clear the threads as soon as possible. If 1001 people all tried to request this action at the same time, the 1001st individual would be queued until one of the other 1000 threads freed up, meaning they could be waiting for almost 4 hours. Even if you never see your site getting this kind of load, it's still an excellent vector for a DDoS attack. Just send a few thousand requests to this URL and your server deadlocks.

Also, I have no idea what you're doing, but 1-2 hours to generate an Excel file is absolutely insane. Either you're dealing with way too much data at once, and sending back multi-gigabyte files that will likely fail to even open properly in Excel, or the process by which you're doing it is severely unoptimized.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The file itself is obtained by 14 thousand lines. The main amount of time it takes to appeal to the base of data, stored procedures and counting formulas.

Comment: Still, 1-2 hours of processing time just to create an Excel document is a very clear sign of a problem. Maybe the server needs more resources (RAM, cores, etc.), but you should definitely focus on optimizing *that* rather than trying to bandaid a bad solution by keeping the user updated on the progress.